# Can't use echo function in PHP on Ubuntu

Tags: php

Just create my first droplet to Digital Ocean.

I have a `Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64`.

This is working:

```
<?= phpinfo(); ?>
```

This is not working:

```
<? echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

It just show in the inspect element tools: `<? echo phpinfo(); ?>`.

Do I missed something ?

Thanks.

Comment: enable short tags

Comment: BTW, you don't need to echo the phpinfo() call.